# How do I emulate holding down a keyboard key in C++

Tags: c++, keyboard, clr

I'm making a virtual piano auto player, you just paste the sheet and it will play(presses the keys specified in the sheet), but I'm having trouble on making the code hold down a key so it syncs with the song but I don't know how, here how I press my keys:

```
                    INPUT input[1];
                    ZeroMemory(input, sizeof(input));

                    input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                    input[0].ki.wVk = x; // <-- x is = to char from a char array

                    SendInput(ARRAYSIZE(input), input, sizeof(INPUT));

                    Sleep(delay);

                    input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                    input[0].ki.wVk = x;// <-- x is = to char from a char array
                    input[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

                    SendInput(ARRAYSIZE(input), input, sizeof(INPUT));

                    Sleep(delay);
```

Comment: I am not sure you want the same delay for key down versus key up.

Comment: yeah all the same delay